# Sharepoint CSOM version conflict

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

Currently im trying to make sense of what causes the following lines to produce version conflict. Ive done my research but a lot of my search seems to be pointing to cache issue. But i would like to know specifically which of the fieldValues is conflicting with the previous call. Thanks.

```
ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = list.AddItem(listItemCreationInfo);
oListItem["Title"] = "HelloFromCode";
oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();

string filePath = @"";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
fs.CopyTo(ms);
AttachmentCreationInformation newFile = new AttachmentCreationInformation { ContentStream = ms, FileName = "Test.docx" };

oListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(newFile);
oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now if i try to change the title, not attaching files to the item, it works.

```
oListItem["Title"] = "HelloFromCode2";
oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

If changing the name again causes version conflict, it does make sense a bit but it works. Which cause confusion since i dont really understand the root cause of version conflict.

And if i remove the first context.ExecuteQuery(), it works (Which does make sense since nothing has been changed before executed).

Thanks again.

Comment: `context.ExecuteQuery();` I'd guess that `context.ExecuteQuery();` just executes the query, it doesn't refresh the values of the loaded list items. This means that the version number you use in subsequent modifications no longer matches the version of the items in SharePoint. This would make a *lot* of sense as CSOM is just a client API, that runs over a very slow connection (HTTP). Clients are meant to make as many modifications as possible in a *single* query. Which means, removing the first `ExecuteQuery` is the correct way to work

Comment: If you can't make all modifications at once (why?), you'll have to reload the items before reying to make more changes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the response. However, why is it if im changing the title on the 2nd time, it works? If my first ExecuteQuery() changes the version, then the 2nd time should causes the version conflict also. To answer "can't make all modifications at once", yes, the previous implementation of our library doesnt really follow the best practice of CSOM. Will be looking to enhance it.